# Cannot Access Attribute In Django Template

Tags: django, templates, model, attributes

View:

```
def details(request, id):
    event = Event.objects.filter(id=id)
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'Event' : event})
```

Template:

```
{% if Event %}

    <h1>Event Name: {{ Event.name }}</h1>

{% else %}

    No Event.

{% endif %}
```

Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField('event date')
    on_sale = models.DateTimeField('on sale time')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

When I load the page it just loads `Event Name:`. When I remove the `.name` attribute it loads the event as it is entered in the db but it won't load any attributes from the object. Appreciate any help/advice, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use get instead of filter:

```
event = Event.objects.get(id=id)
```

If you want to use filter in templete try this:

```
{% for item in Event %}
    <h1>Event Name: {{ item.name }}</h1>
{% empty %}
    No Event.
{% endfor %}
```